# How to resolve this ambiguity in my C program?

Tags: c

I am learning to code C (I am a beginner) and recently came across a problem which asked me to write a C code which lets the following people:

1. above 18 and below 90 (both inclusive)
2. who have a vip pass

drive a car.
Here is my attempt at it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// &&, || , ! is for 'and', 'or' and 'not' respectively. in if statements.
int main()
{
    int age, Vippasscheck;
    printf("Welcome to the land of illegal driving\n");
    printf("Do you have a vip pass?\n1)Yes\n2)No\n");
    scanf("%d", &Vippasscheck);
    if (Vippasscheck == 1)
    {
        printf("Congratulations, You can drive!\n");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("Please enter your age\n");
        scanf("%d", &age);
        if (age > 90 || age < 18)
        {
            printf("Sorry, You cannot drive!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Congratulations, You can drive!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine and all this works for me but the solution given is like this (here is where the ambiguity arises):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int age;
    int vipPass = 0;
    vipPass = 1;

    printf("Enter your age\n");
    scanf("%d", &age); 

    
    if ((age <= 90 && age>=18) || (vipPass==1))
    {
        printf("You are above 18 and below 90, you can drive\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You cannot drive\n");
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

The solution mentioned here first defines an integer `vippass` and then assigns it the value 0 and then in the next line redefines it the value 1?

> int vipPass = 0;
> vipPass = 1;

I am unable to understand how can one variable be assigned something in first line and then reassign it something else? I am a beginner.

Actually the person whose lectures I was watching to understand C Said initially that "I can keep the vip pass value to zero for everyone else, but here I am giving myself a vip pass" and then he added the second line.

---

Edit: I now understand a very important thing about C. You can define the value of a variable(initializing it)(for some initial set of instructions) and then at some later point reassign its value for another set of instructions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
int a=5;
printf("the value of a is %d\n", a);
a=7;
printf("the value of a is %d\n", a);

return 0;

}
```

the output of this is:

> the value of a is 5
>  the value of a is 7

This happened because Compiler reads the code line by line. This property is what people use, to do different things at different intervals (i.e. at different places in their code), by assigning the same variable differently at different points.

So yes, your code won't be messed up if you assign it different values at different points, and the initial part of code will use initial assigned value of the code and final part of the code will use final part of the assigned value of the same variable.

Comment: Variables can be assigned both in declaration (`int vipPass = 0;`) and anywhere else afterwards (`vipPass = 1;`).

Comment: Assigning `vipPass` to 0 and then immediately 1 makes no sense (why wouldn't you just assign 1 to it the first time?), but it's perfectly ok to re-assign variables. For example, in a loop you'll often see something like `i = i  + 1;` -- re-assigning `i` to be one larger.

Comment: That is how variables work. You define and assign values to it. Unless it is final, you can reassign similar type of value to it.

Comment: @PaulHankin Ok so doing this changes the initially assigned variable's value right?

Comment: @Xiobiq thankyou so much first of all, Secondly does redefining it somewhere else changes the output of initially designed programs which use its value(initially defined value to give right results) right?

Comment: @Damstridium assigning / reassigning value is not redefining the variable. And yes, assigning value to a variable might change the program behavior and output. In the provided second example, the fact that `vipPass==1` means that the program will output `you can drive` unconditionally, and this is not the case if we would have `vipPass==0`.

Comment: Was the person giving the lecture younger than 18 or older than 90? `:-)` Good to know that when I am 90 (and some months) I will still be considered "under 90" from the text of the print statement... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 where? can you pin point the line? are you trying to point our this one?`printf("You are above 18 and below 90, you can drive\n");`?

Comment: I think its correct `:-)`  as he has used `<=90`

Comment: @Damstridium A person cannot be both "below 90" and 90 at the same time... Just a trivial observation...

Comment: @Fe2O3 yup didn't consider 90! you are right ! :P

Comment: @Damstridium Beginner coder? Read up on "off by one" mistakes... It's a common source of bugs in code... If you are aware/alert to them, you might save yourself hours of grief hunting for something so simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always reassign new values to a variable; that's why it's called a variable, after all, and it happens all the time in programming. The important thing is that the data type must be correct, but in this case `vipPass` has been declared as an integer, and gets integer values assigned.

Although I must say this is, in fact, unnecessarily confusing. What often happens is that programmers declare a variable without initialising it, i.e., they define it (with its type) but don't assign it a value:

```
int vipPass;
```

Here we have declared `vipPass` as an integer variable but not given it a value. If we go beyond that and not only declare it but give it its first value, that's called an initialisation:

```
int vipPass = 0;
```

Here we have initialised vipPass to zero. It does not prevent us from giving it a different value later on (as `vipPass = 1;` does), but it is indeed quite pointless to initialise it to zero and then, immediately afterwards, give it a new value. The more customary way would be to either initialise it to one immediately with `int vipPass = 1;` or to separate declaration and first value assignment, but without the zero value in between:

```
int vipPass;
vipPass = 1;
```